# jQuery dosen't run on my computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

So I have been trying to implement the transition into my window with jquery and it is clearly not working in my favor. So I want to make something similar to that.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AdrpK

In fact, just to do the test run, I copied and pasted the same code into Dreamweaver and tried to run it and it is not transitioning to the next window, seem its stuck and not sliding the second window up. I have used every single possible way and it is not working. I am using google jquery API, but no luck. I have been trying to figure it out and now I am going crazy. Please help me.

Thats what I am using for Google jQuery API src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"

The JS that is required for the sliding transition, I am putting it in the external file and then attaching it to the document with this link |
script src="slider.js" /script

All and all, there is no luck and I don't know what to do. Is there anyone that can tell me what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Did you checked for any issue/ error stack trace in console tab of browser ?

Comment: you don't need to add `http:`, the current code should work for both `http` and `https`

Comment: Maybe because you are viewing the file in local system using `file://`, browser might not allow including or executing external Javascript in there.

Comment: To those who are not already familiar, links beginning with `//` and *not* `http:` or `https:` are called "protocol-relative URLs", and are valid.

Comment: if you are viewing your file locally without web server than add `http`

Comment: Jquery script must be change. I have provide corrected version as an answer

Comment: So I did put the file on server and I see no changes. The slider still not transitioning to the other page. Also, I did change the code to what Sajitha suggested and I see nothing happening.

Comment: Is there a way to attach the file here so you anyone can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Your script code must be change like this. Example http://jsfiddle.net/ybh2f/

```
var slider = $('.slider');
    wrapper = $('#wrapper');
    animating = false;
    current = 0;
    lengthDiv = slider.length;
    delay = 1500;

$(slider).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchor = $(this);
    if(!animating){
        animating = true;
        current = $(anchor).parent().index();
        wrapper.removeClass().addClass('slide'+current);
        setTimeout(function(){
            animating = false;
        }, delay);

    }
});

$(document).keydown(function(e){var key = e.keyCode;if(key == 38 || key == 40)e.preventDefault();});
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(!animating){
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if(key == 38 && current > 0){
            $(slider[current - 1]).trigger('click');
        }else if(key == 40 && current < lengthDiv - 1){
            $(slider[current + 1]).trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
$(document).mousewheel(function(e, deltaY){
    if(!animating){
        if(deltaY > 0 && current > 0){
            $(slider[current - 1]).trigger('click');
        }else if(deltaY < 0 && current < lengthDiv - 1){
            $(slider[current + 1]).trigger('click');
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

And also use Jquery library 
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js